# Copying files from imported .jar dependency

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have added a .jar file to my dependencies which contains some .avsc files I would like to use.  I also have a .gradle file that takes a directory of .avsc files and compiles them into .java classes.

How can I get gradle to copy over the .avsc files inside my .jar dependency into a folder in my project so that they can be compiled into .java classes?

Comment: The answer depends on how exactly your build logic (or Avro plugin) expects to be told where the `.avsc` files are located.

Comment: @Peter The gradle file that compiles .avsc files into .java?  That piece just takes in a directory with .avsc files in it.  
Or were you talking about the piece that is copying the .avsc files from the .jar?  I had hoped to use something like the gradle copyTask to just grab all the .avsc files inside the .jar dependency and copy them over, but I'm not sure how to do that.